# Security warnings for plugins via Jenkins CLI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to monitor my Jenkins instances by using the Jenkins CLI. Most important are security warnings like given in the [Jenkins Security Advisories](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisories/). Those are shown in the GUI in the upper right corner by red and orange warning symbols:
[image]

I can use the CLI to list all my plugins and possible updates for these:

`java -jar ./jenkins-cli.jar <host> -auth <token> list-plugins | grep -E '\([0-9].[0-9].*\)'`

This returns a three columned list like

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| docker-commons | Docker Commons Plugin | 1.20 (1.21) |

where 1.20 tells me the currently installed version and (1.21) tells me the currently available version.

But still I could not find a CLI-call to tell whether a listed plugin has a known vulnerability. This information seems only to be available in the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-plugins-security-warnings/2266/2.

It seems there's no native call to get those information. But one can curl the latest information from https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.actual.json.

Then you probably need to code the rest of it yourself. You find the security alerts in the *warnings* part of the json. In each warning you find a subsection "versions" where *lastVersion* probably means the last affected version by this warning. By using the (hopefully well-kept) *pattern* you can compare your used version to the *latestVersion*.

I'm currently trying to build a usable bash-script for this task and will update my answer later on when I have finished the script but since I'm not a bash scripting guy this might take a while.

**Edit**: I got it working. Maybe it's helpful for anyone else, but as I said, I'm not the bash-scripting guy.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DELIMITER=";"
#Getting all information from the Jenkins Update Center
items=$(curl -qLs https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.actual.json)

#Getting installed plugins from Jenkins
results=$(java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <host>  -auth <token> list-plugins)

#and writing it to an array.
readarray -t plugins <<<"$results"

for i in "${!plugins[@]}"; do
  #keep format (with whitespaces):
  #matrix-project                     Matrix Project Plugin                                            772.v494f19991984 (785.v06b_7f47b_c631)
  formattedLine=$(echo "${plugins[$i]}");

  #replace 2 or more whitespaces by the delimiter.
  #matrix-project;Matrix Project Plugin;772.v494f19991984 (785.v06b_7f47b_c631)
  replacedWhitespaces=$(echo "$formattedLine" | sed "s/ \{2,\}/$DELIMITER/g")

  #split result into an array
  #[0]matrix-project
  #[1]Matrix Project Plugin
  #[2]772.v494f19991984 (785.v06b_7f47b_c631)
  IFS="$DELIMITER" read -r -a parts <<< "$replacedWhitespaces"

  #check whether there is an update available or not 
  #<=> if there is a () separated by a whitespace or not
  if [[ "${parts[2]}" =~ \ |\' ]] 
    then
      IFS=' ' read -r -a subparts <<< "${parts[2]}";
      parts[2]=$(echo "${subparts[0]}")
      parts[3]=$(echo "${subparts[1]}")
    else
      parts[3]=""
  fi
    
  echo "name: ${parts[0]}"
  echo "description: ${parts[1]}"  
  echo "Used Version: ${parts[2]}"
  echo "Latest Version: ${parts[3]}"
  echo "Vulnerabilities:"
 
  #find vulnerabilities to this plugin:
  vulnerabilities=$(echo "$items" | ./jq-win64 -c -r --arg pluginName "${parts[0]}" '.warnings[] | select(.name==$pluginName)')
 
  #separate vulnerabilities
  IFS=$'\n' res=($vulnerabilities)
  
  #get the relevant content from each vulnerability
  for r in "${!res[@]}"; do
    lastVersion=$(echo "${res[$r]}" | ./jq-win64 -r -c '.versions[0]|.lastVersion')
    id=$(echo "${res[$r]}" | ./jq-win64 -r -c '.|.id')
    message=$(echo "${res[$r]}" | ./jq-win64 -r -c '.|.message')
    url=$(echo "${res[$r]}" | ./jq-win64 -r -c '.|.url')
    echo "* <=$lastVersion: $id - $message ($url)";
  done;
  
  echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
done
```